# Change web service URL's in App.Config

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a small sharepoint project which integrates into a larger sharepoint project. My project uses two web services. I've added them using `Web Reference` (embedded in the Service Reference) dialog in `VS2010`. We have two sets of web services - one for testing and one for production. When I deploy the app locally, the web services settings are written to the web.config file located at `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\` on my local machine. The section looks something like this -

```
 <applicationSettings>
    <XXX.YYY.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="XXX_YYY_ZZZ_WS1" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://<TEST_IPAddress>/WebService/WS1.asmx</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="XXX_YYY_ZZZ_WS2" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://<TEST_IPAddress>/WebService/WS2.asmx</value>
      </setting>
    </XXX.YYY.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
```

The difference between the test and production web services is just the IP Address. When I change the IP address to production, the app is not using the new values. I had to go back to VS, update the `Web Reference URL` in the `Properties` dialog to the correct production urls, then re-deploy the package again. This is tedious as I constantly keep switching from test to production web service url's. I want to be able to change the IP address in the app.config, refresh the page in the browser and it should pick up the new urls.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you change the webservice url in code then you will not have to repeat the build process. you can change like this

```
WebServiceObjectName webService = new WebServiceObjectName (); 
webService.Uri = [IPaddress or DNS name]
```

Comment: I think I may have confused you. The snippet code I posted are the urls of two TEST web services. It is not one for test and one for production. They both are TEST. I want to able to change to production IP's and the app should automatically pick it up.

Comment: Then you can have 4 keys 2 for test and 2 for production and one key to point the deployment type i.e Test of Live

Comment: I understand your approach but am not sure on how to implement them. Do you want me to have two more entries in the `<XXX.YYY.Properties.Settings>` section for Production? Could you please elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: Forget about four keys. I think if you change the webservice url in code then you will not have to repeat the build process. you can change like this WebServiceObjectName webService = new WebServiceObjectName ();
webService.Uri = [IPaddress or DNS name];

Comment: Thanks, but I still need to have a entry in the AppSettings to figure out if it's Production or Test, right? I can then change this one setting on the fly and the URL's should switch.

Comment: Now you dont have to figure out as you are using url key and setting the url of your web services at runtime so you dont need to build.

Comment: But how does the app know if it needs to use test url vs production url without a flag somewhere? I'm slightly confused.

Comment: you will only have one url that will change when you change to test to procution

Answer (score 0):

We do this like so:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPublicWS"
                openTimeout="00:00:05"
                sendTimeout="00:03:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                closeTimeout="00:00:30"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="262144" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="262144"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="131072" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
              <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
              </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <!-- Production -->
        <endpoint name="SvLive" address="http://sv.com/PublicWS/PublicWS.svc/PublicWS" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPublicWS" contract="SV.IPublicWS" />

        <!-- Test -->
        <endpoint name="SvTest" address="http://staging.sv.com/PublicWS/PublicWS.svc/PublicWS" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPublicWS" contract="SV.IPublicWS" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

​
Then, to get a client reference to this webservice:

```
public static PublicWSClient Client()
{
#if PRODUCTION
    return new PublicWSClient("SvLive");
#else
    return new PublicWSClient("SvTest");
#endif
}
```

Which is called like:

```
var sv = PublicWSClient.Client();
```

This prevents any of the manual steps you describe, and allows both test and live to be captured in a single config file ready to be checked in.